# automating the upgrade to django 1.x

Tags: django, django-admin

I've been using a pre 1.0 version of django (a dev version somewhere around .97),

And now I'm considering upgrading to 1.x (I grabbed the latest thing from the svn).

There have been some changes to the way the admin interface works, so now I have to edit all my `models.py` files and create new `admin.py` files.

I remember seeing a tool that supposedly automated (most of) this process, but that was a long time ago and I don't remember where it was (or maybe my memory is wrong)

Is there such a tool? Where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might also be helpful:
http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/603/

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is this page: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.0-porting-guide/.

It contains info on the changes, and a link to the script that will auto-generate a 1.0-compatible admin.py file based on your models.